# Nexus 7 (4.2.2) stuck as read-only on Ubuntu 13.04 (PC)

Tags: 13.04, permissions, android, nexus-7, read-only

I have a Nexus 7 running the latest Android (4.2.2) that seems to be stuck as read-only. I cannot transfer any files to or from the device though I am free to look through it. Permissions are:

View Content: Only Owner
Change Content: Nobody
Access Content: Nobody

And when I try to change the permission I get this error:

Operation not supported by backend

I'm baffled. This is a stock install of Ubuntu on my PC and the install isn't that old. Am I missing a lib or something? I feel the need to say it works fine on Windows 7.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: You are obviously doing something wrong here. Set your device to MTP mode and follow the tutorials for MTP. Everything will be fine. No permissions to change, nothing.

Comment: Nexus 7 only comes in MTP. I can access the device, I just can't write to the device.

Answer (score 0):

Run these command in a terminal:

`sudo chown username:username /media/your-device`

changing your "username" for the user name you use to log in and changing "your-device" for what you device is mounted under.

Then run:

`sudo chmod 755 -R /dev/sdX`

Change X for you devices ID

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm getting this error on the first command:

"chown: cannot access ‘/media/nexus7’: No such file or directory."

I'm not sure what the issue is. When going to the directory in question the folders I have are floppy, a shortcut to floppy and a folder with my username, inside that folder is my pendrive.

Comment: @BiggJJ Newer Android devices rely on MTP instead of UMS mode and therefore will not act like a USB stick.

Comment: 13.04 has MTP support built in and it seems nobody else is having this issue. If it didn't have MTP support I wouldn't be able to access the tablet at all.

Comment: ahhhh, I was unaware of this, as MTP sucks.